# how do I scrape data from a dynamic website and import it into google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping

I am trying to make a google sheet with a bunch of shoe prices from various websites. I am attempting to scrape data from GOAT.com, more specifically [this](https://www.goat.com/sneakers/yeezy-boost-350-v2-pure-oat-hq6316?srsltid=AfAwrE4KGXn3sX_rCPjQYek-JdESrmSbj6tm3CXlB3roz8wKRdIyBl52-XY) shoe, but have discovered the website is dynamic, therefore I can't use importXML, like I have been for the past few websites. How would I find a workaround to this as well as get a specific shoe size for such shoe?

I tried to use the following:
=IMPORTXML("https://www.goat.com/sneakers/yeezy-boost-350-v2-pure-oat-hq6316?srsltid=AfAwrE4KGXn3sX_rCPjQYek-JdESrmSbj6tm3CXlB3roz8wKRdIyBl52-XY", "/html/body/div[1]/div/main/div/div[2]/footer/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[34]/div/span")

This gave me an error that says "Could not fetch url: [https://www.goat.com/sneakers/yeezy-boost-350-v2-pure-oat-hq6316?srsltid=AfAwrE4KGXn3sX_rCPjQYek-JdESrmSbj6tm3CXlB3roz8wKRdIyBl52-XY"](https://www.goat.com/sneakers/yeezy-boost-350-v2-pure-oat-hq6316?srsltid=AfAwrE4KGXn3sX_rCPjQYek-JdESrmSbj6tm3CXlB3roz8wKRdIyBl52-XY%22).